# Sum and multiplication on graded algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-algebras

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $G$ a commutative group under addition. This algebra is called a $G$-graded if there exists a family $\{A_{g}\}_{g\in G}$ of vector subspaces of $\mathcal{A}$ such that:
$$\mathcal{A} = \bigoplus_{g\in G}A_{g}$$
and $A_{g}A_{h} \subseteq A_{g+h}$.

**Question:** The above definition is the usual definition of a $G$-graded algebra. But the direct sum in the right hand side of the equality must be an algebra too. What are the operations (sum, multiplication and scalar multiplication) defined in such direct sum? Are these operations *always* defined to be the natural ones? By the natural ones I mean that, if $a = (a_{g})_{g\in G}, b = (b_{g})_{g\in G}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$:
$$a+b := (a_{g}+b_{g})_{g\in G} \quad ab := \sum_{g,h\in G}a_{g}b_{h} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \lambda a := (\lambda a_{g})_{g\in G}$$

Comment: Notice that the formula you suggest for the product is incompatible with the formulat $A_gA_h\subset A_{gh}$.

Comment: You seem to be implying the multiplication operation on the direct sum is componentwise, which is completely wrong. (Plus, you seem to be assuming $a_gb_g$ automatically means something when $a_g,b_g$ are simply elements of a vector space ${\cal A}_g$, which doesn't make sense to me.) BTW, the prototypical example of a $G$-graded algebra would be the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]=\bigoplus_{g\in G} \mathbb{C}g$.

Comment: @runway44 ops, my mistake. I didn't mean that, of course. The formula I was going to post was the distributive formula, but I didn't pay enough attention when posting it. I'm going to edit it!

Comment: Your $ab$ needs to be a $G$-indexed tuple, just like $a,b,a+b,\lambda a$ are, no?

Comment: @runway44 I edited my post. Btw, each $a_{g}$ and $b_{g}$ are elements of vector spaces of $\mathcal{A}$, so these vector spaces inherite the operations of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @runway44 yes, of course ab must be a $G$-indexed tuple. So, the conclusion is that I don't know how to define the multiplication haha. Can you help me here?

Comment: Well, if $a_u\in{\cal A}_u$ and $a_v\in{\cal A}_v$ then $a_ua_v\in{\cal A}_{uv}$. Therefore, if you want to find the $g$-coordinate of $ab$, you need to collect all terms $a_ub_v$ with $uv=g$, in other words $$ ab=\Big(\sum_{uv=g}a_ub_v\Big)_{g\in G} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the direct sum in the right hand side of the equality must be an algebra too.

The operations are the ones defined by the algebra structure; the equality with the direct sum is just a $k$-vector space equality. The direct sum of rngs can be nonunital for inifnite indices, however there are unital graded algebras with inifnitely many non-trivial homogenous components (those are concrete examples in which we definitely cannot have an equality as algebras). For example, the ring $k[x]$ has a $\mathbb Z$-grading induced by the degree of a polynomial.

From the comments:

> Btw, each $a_g$ and $b_g$ are elements of vector spaces of $A$, so these vector spaces inherite the operations of.

Well, we know how to multiply them according to the algebra structure on $A$, but their product lies on $A_{g^2}$ which is never $A_g$ unless $g = 1$. Hence multiplication cannot be defined "component wise" on each subspace.

However, if you know the homogeneous components of two elements and how multiplication works between homogeneous elements, you can recover the operations. Namely, if $a = \sum_{g \in G} a_g$ and $b = \sum_{h \in G} b_h$ (and by usual abuse of notation all but finitely many elements of each sum are zero) then

$$
a+b = \sum_{g \in G} a_g + b_g, \text{ so }(a+b)_g = a_g+b_g;
$$

$$
\lambda \cdot a = \sum_{g \in G} \lambda a_g, \text{ so } (\lambda a)_g = \lambda \cdot a_g,
$$

and

$$
ab = \sum_{g,h \in G} a_g b_h = \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{s \in G} a_s a_{s^{-1}g}, \quad (ab)_g = \sum_{s \in G}a_sb_{s^{-1}g}. 
$$

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Technically $k[x]$ is $\Bbb N$-graded; $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is $\Bbb Z$-graded.

Comment: @runway44 $k[x]$ is both $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ graded, just define $(k[x]) = kt^n$ for non-negative $n$ and $(k[x])_n = 0$ otherwise. OP's definition of grading specifies that $G$ should be an abelian **group**.